# Make user-friendly URL in Codeigniter with multi-language support

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3, user-friendly

I have created a multi-language website.
Facing issue while creating SEO user-friendly URL.

current URL:
http://localhost/example/en/user/myaccount OR
http://localhost/example/fr/user/myaccount

want to change it with
http://localhost/example/en/myaccount OR
http://localhost/example/fr/user/myaccount

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl|id|es)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/en', '/de', '/fr','/es' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl|id|es)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

also tried with

```
$route["myaccount"] = "user/myaccount";
```

```
$route["^(en|de|fr|nl|id|es)$/myaccount"] = "user/myaccount";
```

Nothing will work in this case. Already used following in routes.php file other demo projects with out multi-language. There it's work perfectly.

```
$route["myaccount"] = "user/myaccount";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can consult the documentation for routes here
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

and for your problem

```
$route["(:any)/myaccount"] = "user/myaccount/$1";
```

Comment: myaccount is a function in file/class controller user or its a class
if myaccount is a class 

try $route["(:any)/myaccount"] = "user/myaccount/index/$1";

Comment: user is my controller and myaccount is function